# Electron density for discrete set of states

Tags: statistical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Suppose I am solving the Schrödinger equation for a system with a discrete set of fermionic states $\{\psi_{n}\}$ with energies $\{ E_{n} \}$. Is it correct in this case that the density is simply given by

$$\rho = \sum_{n} \lvert \psi_{n} \lvert^2 f(E_{n}-\mu), $$

where $f$ denotes the Fermi distribution of the system.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, assuming the system to be in equilibrium. See Equation 98 in:

> Pribram-Jones, Aurora, et al. "Thermal density functional theory in
> context." Frontiers and Challenges in Warm Dense Matter. Springer
> International Publishing, 2014. 25-60.
>
> [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-04912-0_2) and [PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3043.pdf)